# Expected behaviour in Sitecore for config include files with patch:delete

Tags: web-config, sitecore

I am working on moving the custom configuration settings for a Sitecore (6.2) project into a separate `App_Config\Include` file.  I am testing my changes using the sitecore page /sitecore/admin/ShowConfig.aspx.  My question is **what is the expected behaviour when using the `<patch:delete />` element?**

In my include file I have the following:

```
<setting name="Preview.DefaultSite">
  <patch:delete/>
</setting>
```

When I look at ShowConfig.aspx I see the following:

```
<setting name="Preview.DefaultSite" value="website">
  <delete/>
</setting>
```

Is this correct and expected behaviour, or should the `<setting name="Preview.DefaultSite">` element completely disappear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The element should completely disappear and this works as expected for me in Sitecore 6.5 (update-5) and I know it worked in 6.4 as well.

Which version of Sitecore are you using?

All the patch attributes are mentioned here: [All About web.config Include Files with the Sitecore ASP.NET CMS](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2011/05/All-About-web-config-Include-Files-with-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx) but the comments suggest some people had issues with this. [This article from 2010 on web.config includes](http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2010/09/23/sitecore-web-config-include-files-auto-include/) also mentions you cannot delete but like I said, it works in the newer versions.

You could always patch the attribute to remove the value:

```
<setting name="Preview.DefaultSite">
  <patch:attribute name="value"></patch:attribute>
</setting>
```

Comment: Ok thanks for this. I'm using 6.2. I've seen those links already but was confused brian pedersens blog when he said you can't delete, despite the documentation suggesting that you can!

Comment: That will probably be it, I seem to recall this was the same issue we had with 6.2